# Troubles with integrating Jquery and Jquery-UI frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

After a long time I try again to work with jquery. The last time it worked great but now I have to run to bring it trouble. Have tried to break the problem down into simple parts and have included the HTML, JS and CSS file created to eliminate as many errors as possible. I think that I have not correctly using jquery, but can not find my error.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
 height: 100%;
 width:  100%;
 background-color: #FCF65A;
}

#slider{
 height: 100%;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: #88E453;
 margin-left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#slider').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

According to my understanding of this, the Green bars should left click on the edge of NEM but disappear?

I'd appreciate any help. I've been seeking the error now for almost 2 days.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English

Comment: The solution to his problem is to put the test.js script after the slider div declaraion, or run onload. I hope he can read english :-)

Comment: How does it being in another language make it off topic? at least it isn't in poorly written english that we can't understand, we can send this off to google translate and be able to understand what he's asking. If anything it should be closed because it's a duplicate, his javascript includes are out of order.

Comment: @KevinB I tried translating it, but I think there's more than just the includes being out of order. Hard to really gauge given the use of colloquialisms.

Comment: jquery.js and test.js need to be swapped in position, and either he has a copy paste error, or he has an extra }) in his code. and if it's an extra }), he's likely missing document.ready.

Comment: Remove the duplicate '});', this solves the problem. Here is a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EKG5w/

Comment: @usefulcat your jsfiddle doesn't represent his code, he isn't using onload as far as we can see.

Comment: @KevinB — http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684

Comment: First you have a typo in including the jquery-ui source (forgot the closing quote). Second the order to include is (1) jquery, (2) jquery-ui, (3) test.js. Third, you have to enclose the click-function definition with $(document).ready(function() { .. });. Then it will work as expected

Comment: I actually put down than question in german but for some reason the website has translated it automatically in to english.

Comment: Kevin B was right, I just had to put the test.js after jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui.js. Thanks for your help!